# Can I say RDF Schema (RDFS) is a ontology of RDF?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, owl, rdfs

I have a bit of confusion about RDF and RDF Schema (RDFS). I have read some doc in which they mentioned that rdfs is to define vocabularies for RDF.

Based on this definition, can I say RDFS is one of the ontology like OWL or Dublin Core?

Richard

Answer (score 5):

A schema is a type of ontology, yes.

But, RDFS is a schema language, like OWL, not an ontology, like Dublin Core, or SKOS, or Good Relations.

Schema languages (or ontology languages) are used to write ontologies, they are not ontologies themselves.

Comment: As complement to excellent answer: RDFS is used to build the schema on the top on your RDF data, it helps you to defined hierarchies of types.

Comment: hi Steve

Thank you for your reply, but I got more confused now. Can you give me some example? 

My knowledge is that ontology is like a list with domain vocabularies (such as: title, creator...etc.), but what is Schema language?

Comment: @Richard, a schema language is a language for creating a schema. In order to create a schema or an ontology, you need a language that provides you with terminology to describe the things that the schema consists of, i.e. terms such as `Class`, `SubClassOf`, `domain`, `range`, etc. That is what RDFS (and OWL) provide.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that RDFS is in fact an ontology. But that heavily depends on your understanding of the concept ontology.

I like the definition of [(Studer et. al., Knowledge engineering: Principles and methods, 1998)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0169023X97000566):

> An ontology is a formal, explicit specification of a shared
>   conceptualization. Conceptualization refers to an abstract model of
>   some phenomenon in the world by having identified the relevant
>   concepts of that phenomenon. Explicit means that the type of concepts
>   used, and the constraints on their use are explicitly defined. [...]
>   Formal refers to the fact that the ontology should be
>   machine-readable. Shared reflects the notion that an ontology captures
>   consensual knowledge, that is, it is not private of some individual,
>   but accepted by a group.

In this understanding RDFS is an ontology, regardless of the fact that RDFS is usually used to define other ontologies. The described phenomenon in RDFS are classes, properties and their relations.